# Generating first simple path between two nodes with networkx.all_simple_paths does not terminate

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to generate a simple path between a pair of nodes in a networkx.MultiDiGraph.

The graph has 1798 edges and 754 nodes and its GML representation is found here: https://pastebin.com/QdKsE1xd

The code I use to load the graph from GML format:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_gml("test.gml", label='id')
```

The two nodes have id's `11` and `746` and by the following code, there exists a path between these two nodes:

```
print(nx.has_path(G,11,746)
-> True
print(nx.dijkstra_path(G,11,746)
-> [11, 10, 272, 534, 311, 310, 313, 426, 423, 428, 737, 750, 749, 748, 747, 746]
```

But when I try to generate the first simple path, the code never terminates:

```
next(nx.all_simple(G,11,746)
```

I would expect the underlying depth-first search to quickly find a first path in this relatively small graph but it does not terminate (timeout 2 minutes).

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, but I guess that is worth trying.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `all_simple_paths` rather than one of the shortest path algorithms?  I think the algorithm you're using may find all of the possible paths before returning any.  There is combinatorial explosion in this, so it wouldn't be surprising it might take a very long time.

Comment: Yes. In reality I want the first ``k`` simple paths for some number ``k``. And no, nx.all_simple_paths returns a generator that finds path one by one (using some variant of DFS, c.f notes in https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths)